# Is Fermentation without airlock possible in bottle?

Tags: fermentation, bottle-conditioning, primary-fermentation, airlock, pressure

I added sugar and bread yeast to a bottle(plastic bottle) of juice and it's about 3 days that it's fermentation process got started and I can see a lot of bubbles are coming up.

Now the bottle is highly stretched due to the high pressure of gas released in the fermentation process and it's about to explode.

I have a few questions.

1. Is it bad to produce beer like this? ( i don't have money to buy airlock).
2. Should I open the bottle every 12 hours to let the gas come out?
3. If I open it frequently to let the gas come out, does it causes the generated alcohol to evaporate?

Any advice or help would be much appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it bad to produce beer like this? ( i don't have money to buy airlock).

I wouldn't call it ideal, but it is fine. The only purpose of an airlock is to allow air to escape and not enter.

> Should I open the bottle every 12 hours to let the gas come out?

Yes, I would open it to let it degass to prevent the bottle from exploding during the few days of primary fermentation. Not totally degassing often may cause this to be slightly carbonated.

> If I open it frequently to let the gas come out, does it causes the generated alcohol to evaporate?

No, it won't cause the alcohol to evaporate. It is simply letting the CO2 escape.

Comment: thank you so much for your help! And happy new year!