# is my still bubbling beer ready?

Tags: fermentation, yeast, beer, bottle-conditioning, bubble

I made my beer about 5 days ago I mean it's about 5 days that it's vigorously bubbling. I made it in the bottle under a high pressure. Please take a look at my previous question to see how I'm fermenting my beer.

[Is Fermentation without airlock possible in bottle?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/q/25390/18789)

1. Now I want to know now (after 5 days of fermentation) how many percentage of alcohol is generated in my beer?
2. Is it drinkable now even tho it's still bubbling vigorously?
3. Does it ferment faster under high pressure?

Additional info:

```
Beer size: One liter
Amount of sugar: 90 grams
Amount of yeast: Half of a tb spoon
Type of yeast: Bread yeast
Temperature: 25C
Fermentation environment: Completely in bottle
```

[image: bottles]

Comment: You need to read How To Brew by John Palmer, available free online at howtobrew.com. Or The Complete Joy by Charlie Papazian. You are asking questions beneath novice level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the bubbling stop. Then put it in the fridge. Then after a couple of days of clearing put it in the fridge to let the yeast settle out.

Once this is done, carefully puur your fermented liquor off the lees(left over yeast), and drink. Do not expect this to be good, it will be liquid and contain alcohol, but it will likely taste awful.

I have made ginger beer this way and it works really well, but I used specific beer yeast Safale S-04, not bread yeast. But the extreme ginger masked any short comings of the fermentation process.

Re your 3 questions -

- how many percentage of alcohol is generated in my beer?

No idea, without a hydrometer reading before and in current state

- Is it drinkable now even tho it's still bubbling vigorously?

Yes, but may not taste great.

- Does it ferment faster under high pressure?

No this usually stresses the yeast and inhibits their progress.